# Is it possible to remove SPI from IPSec header?

Tags: ipsec, sa

I know that SPI plays an important role in IPsec. But I want to know that:
Is it possible to remove SPI from IPSec header and still get it work?

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think that could be possible. But It´s always depends of the kernel´s implementations.

According to the RFC 4301, a SA is identify by three parameters: IP destination, Security Protocol (AH, ESP) and a SPI.

The SPI is unique, if we had a SA with the same IP destination and same Security Protocol (for example, diferent encryption algorithm) the only parameter that could differentiate the SA is the SPI, needed to map the traffic.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4301